# Concatenate nested JSON structures using jq

Tags: jq

Edit: updated question as example was too simplified to cover specific case:

Suppose I have a json object:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "details": {
        "name": "test",
        "description": "description"
      },
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue",
          "property2": "someOtherValue"
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": {
        "other": "stuff"
      }
    },
    {
      "details": {
        "name": "test2",
        "description": "description2"
      },
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue2",
          "property2": "someOtherValue2"
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": {
        "other": "stuff"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract the two json objects `details` and `properties` and and insert into `item`, replacing all other properties. In this example there are `additionalProperties` that should be ignored, but there could be up to `n` other properties that should also be ignored.

Desired output:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "description",
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue2",
          "property2": "someOtherValue2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "description": "description2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue2",
          "property2": "someOtherValue2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried a few different ways using map - but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I've seen similar solutions involving `reduce` too, however I am yet to get something that works. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `|=` each item in the `.items` array by adding up `.details` and `.properties`:

```bash
jq '.items[] |= .details + .properties'
```

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "description",
      "property1": "someValue",
      "property2": "someOtherValue"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "description": "description2",
      "property1": "someValue2",
      "property2": "someOtherValue2"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EncmEdXWIxR)

---

Edit: With the updated input files, just add `{properties}` as is (replacing `.properties`):

```bash
jq '.items[] |= .details + {properties}'
```

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "description",
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue",
          "property2": "someOtherValue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "description": "description2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "property1": "someValue2",
          "property2": "someOtherValue2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MVk2Gv3DU91)

Comment: thanks! this has helped me progress, but in over simplifying my question i've become unstuck!
how could you do the same, if `properties` is an array? i can update the question if it helps

Comment: @Spanner0jjm Change `.properties` to `{properties}`: `.items[] |= .details + {properties}` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MVk2Gv3DU91)

Answer (score 0):

With `*` operator:

```
jq '.items[] |= (.details * .properties[])' test.json
```

---

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "description",
      "property1": "someValue",
      "property2": "someOtherValue"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "description": "description2",
      "property1": "someValue2",
      "property2": "someOtherValue2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how might this work if properties is an array?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the desired output with the following:

```
jq '.items[] |= .details + {"properties": .properties}'
```

ideally I don't want to specify the key "properties" but am yet to find another way

Comment: [`jq '.items[] |= .details+{properties}'`](https://jqplay.org/s/2LRMpNkqIL8)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions as evidenced by the existing great answers. One solution takes the constructive, albeit slightly repetetive, approach:

```
{
    items: .items | map({
        name: .details.name,
        description: .details.description,
        properties
    })
}
```

Similarly, you can re-construct the items of the array and then update-assign them:

```
.items[] |= {
    name: .details.name,
    description: .details.description,
    properties
}
```